# Fade text overflow

Tags: html, css

I need to fade the text that overflows from my div,
I would know how to do it by simply using a gradient but in that case the gradient would be visible on my background image.

I need to fade the text but still being able to see the background image under.

thank you.
Fabio

Comment: Using overflow:hidden; doesn't do the trick? I'm not sure what you're looking for. If you made a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) I'm sure I could fix it. If you want the background to not hide on overflow, put the background on a container div and set overflow:hidden on the element with text in it. But like I said, I'd know for sure and I'd be able to answer the question if you made a JSFiddle or even posted any relevant code at all.

Comment: the overflow simply cut the text while I need to create a fade out effect.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking I think you need a PNG to do this, one that contains a gradient going from 100% to 0% opacity. It can also be done with rgba (CSS3).

Comment: i thought about that too but in that case when the png is 100% you can see the solid color on top of the background.

Comment: make the solid color of the PNG the same as your background

Comment: I am using a pattern as background :(

Comment: [This](http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/) should help.

Comment: Take a look at [Linear Gradient Masks](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking). Note the background image in the demo is missing, replace with Dev Tools to get a better idea. Doesn't work in IE though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea :

Make the text of the css of the three last lines transparent :

```
color: transparent;
```

Then fill theses lines with a text-shadow.

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1)
```

Then you can fade the shadow for the second and the last line

```
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,5)
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0)
```

It needs a bit of JS but it's simple :)
And will work in every modern browserz

EDIT :
I'm stupid, you can even use rgba for text-color instead of using the text-shadow trick.
And no need of JS, you can select the last lines with nth-child.
You will need JS only if the number of lines is always changing.

EDIT 2 :
We can't use nth-child for lines. There is only ::fist-line.

So it seems impossible without javascript.